# Add separate subdomain routing for frontend and backend (Godaddy, AWS and Firebase)

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, dns, hosting, firebase-hosting

We have an app whose domain is on Godaddy, the frontend (ReactJS) is hosted on Firebase and the backend (Django) is on AWS. We follow subdomain-naming just like Slack does i.e. xyz.ourdomain.com. However, for every customer we have to do these manual steps and wait for hours for records to propagate:

1. Add an `A` record to Godaddy where e.g. `Name` would be `XYZ` and `Value` would be the value provided to us by `Firebase` when we add a custom domain there which is `Value: 151.101.1.195` (Firebase shows this message there: `Your site will show a security certificate warning for a few hours, until the certificate has been provisioned.`)
2. Then we need to authorize our domain URL `xyz.ourdomain.com` on **Firebase** and **Google Cloud Console** (however that is not a major worry for now)
3. The last step is some customisation from backend which is necessary and can be automated by me easily

I just want to know how to create wildcard entries so that when one enters `*.ourdomain.com`, it points to the Firebase hostings. Ideally, we want to remove the time it takes for records to propagate.

Answer (score 0):

This level control is not built into firebase as it is designed to work as your primary domain app, as such you can redirect all subdomains in your DNS to point to your root domain with the following guide:

- Log into your GoDaddy account.
- Click “Domains.”
- Click “Manage DNS.”
- Click Add and select CNAME from the dropdown list.
- Complete the fields listed:

```
Host: The host name should be set to the wildcard (" * ").
Points to: This is the URL you are setting as the destination for the host. ...
```

- Click “Save.”

You additionally have the option for 301 permanent redirects.